# If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for topology $\tau$, then $\tau = \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and  $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a basis.
Let $\tau_{\mathcal{B}}= \{U \subseteq X : \forall x \in U, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}. x\in B \subseteq U\}$.
If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for topology $\tau$, then $\tau = \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$.

**Attempt:**
$(\subseteq)$ Let $U \in \tau$ and $x \in U$ be arbitrary.
Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis, there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for topology $\tau$,
there exists $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ such that
$$U = \bigcup_{B \subseteq \mathcal{C}} B.$$
It follows that $B \subseteq U$ and so, $x \in B \subseteq U$.
Hence, $U \in \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$.

$(\supseteq)$ Let $U \in \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$ be arbitrary.
By definition, for all $x \in U$, there exists $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq U$. It follows that
$U = \bigcup_{x \in U} B_x$.
Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for topology $\tau$, we have $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \tau$. Hence, for all $x \in U$, there exists $B_x \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subseteq U \in \tau$.

Therefore, $\tau = \tau_{\mathcal{B}}$.

Is the above approach correct?
Any comments and helps would be very appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

In the second inclusion the last sentence beginning with "hence" is unnecessary. In the proof of the first inclusion you choose some $B\in \mathcal{B}$ with $x\in B$ this is confusing and unnecessary, in particular it may not be the same $B$ as in the second-last sentence of your proof as those $B$'s depend on $U$. The only thing needed is the representation of $U$ as a union of basis elements, the rest is immediate.

Comment: So, what's the correct answer?

Comment: The second part of your proof is correct. In the first part you should just write: Since $U \in \tau$ there is $\mathcal{C}\subset \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $ U=\bigcup_{V\in \mathcal{C}} V$. Thus, $U\in \tau_\mathcal{B}$.